# separate class for each child

Tags: jquery, class, selection

I'm stuck on something I hope you might be able to help me with. 
I'm using a plugin for a slider on WordPress and need control over each thumbnail.
I want to add a unique ID to each child element within a div so I can style it using CSS.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
<div class="royalControlNavCenterer">
  <a class="current" href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
  <a href="#">5</a>
</div>
```

As you can see a current class is already added by the plugin. What I'm looking for is to similarly, dynamically add a class to each  element so it would look as followed:

```
<div class="royalControlNavCenterer">
  <a id="1" class="current" href="#">1</a>
  <a id="2" href="#">2</a>
  <a id="3" href="#">3</a>
  <a id="4" href="#">4</a>
  <a id="5" href="#">5</a>
</div>
```

This way I can style each thumbnail separately which is needed for my design. I figured jQuery would be the best option for this but I'm open for any suggestions.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".royalControlNavCenterer > a").prop( "id", function( i ) {
    return i + 1;
});
```

---

If 0-based indexing is ok, I.E:

```
<div class="royalControlNavCenterer">
  <a class="current" href="#" id="0">1</a>
  <a href="#" id="1">2</a>
  <a href="#" id="2">3</a>
  <a href="#" id="3">4</a>
  <a href="#" id="4">5</a>
</div>
```

You can get away with

```
$(".royalControlNavCenterer > a").prop("id",​ Number);​
```

Comment: @Adil only if he didn't want 1-indexed, you could do `.prop(id, Number)` ;<

Comment: I like this solution... Much better than mine! Going to use this more often. Thanks!

Comment: @Esailija Did not know that `Number` trick, cool stuff! +1d earlier, but I would do it again if I could.

Comment: I had no idea you could pass a function as a value, but it makes sense now.  How does it know what `i` is?

Comment: @ExplosionPills see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-functionindex-%20oldPropertyValue)

Comment: @ExplosionPills jQuery passes the right `i` to the handler function on every iteration. A lot of methods are capable of accepting a function instead of a simple value (`attr`, `text`, class methods, etc.), I use them a lot.

Comment: Wow, I never expected such fast a great replies. Unfortunatly I'm a complete novice at javascript, what would be the correct place to add this snippet? I assume the sliders js file?

(PS: 0 based indexing is fine as the ID is only so I can have control trough css)

Comment: @JasonSchot somewhere where it's guaranteed that the elements exist by the time the code is executed.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I got confused since I thought an `id` starting with a number is invalid (apparently it's not, though).

Comment: @ExplosionPills it is invalid in CSS but jQuery is hardly CSS-compliant selector syntax. `$("#0")` will work fine. But specifying `#0 { color: red; }` in actual css shouldn't work.

Comment: I looked it up and you are right. 
http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: @Esailija Thanks a million for this!

Edit: so I can't apply CSS to these ID's? That would miss the whole point. Would it be possible to do it with ABC instead?

Comment: @Esailija that's good to know -- also important to note that it is not invalid in HTML.

Comment: If I could be so rude I would like to ask help on one more thing. I can't get it implemented. I've set up a test file but it does not seem to work. Could you please take a look at it? Thanks a ton!

http://bizz-mobile.nl/test.html

Comment: @JasonSchot there is some invisible character that is causing a syntax error. When I copypaste it to my editor, it comes up as `$(".royalControlNavCenterer > a").prop("id",? Number);`. The question mark is not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 1):

This should work... It'll target direct `a` children of `royalControlNavCenterer` and give them an `id` attribute starting at 1 and going up from there.

```
$(".royalControlNavCenterer > a").each(function(i) {
   $(this).attr("id", i+1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do it by adding this at the end of your `body` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    var globalCount = 0;   
    $('.royalControlNavCenterer a').each(function(){
       this.id='id_'+(globalCount++);
    });
});
</script>
```

But I'm not sure I see the point in giving dynamic ids. You don't have to do this to give separate styles.

Demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/LrBxc/ (type F12 to show the console)

It seems I was the only one bothered by the fact that the proposed ids didn't follow the [HTML 4 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) :

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Wow, thanks for the super fast answers! I will try implementing this, any suggestions as to where in my code this snippet would fit bests? 

(I'm a total novice on javascript and the js of the slider plugin is compressed)

Comment: HTML5 allows these types of IDs, so the restrictions of the old standard only apply if one uses the old DOCTYPE I guess.

Comment: @JasonSchot I precised in my answer where you can insert the code.

Comment: In HTML4, `type` is a required attribute on the `script` tag ;).

Comment: @bažmegakapa lol, well played. Updated. The important point about the ids is that not every software you have in your toolchain (including browsers) is magically compatible with HTML 5 relaxed rules just because you don't have an old doctype.

Comment: @dystroy do I understand the jsfiddle correct that the script is in a seperate file and should be embedded from the header of the html page?

Comment: No. Don't use a separate file for this. Simply add the code I provided (or the one of somebody else) in your html/php page, preferably near the end of the body.